# Save A String to a Text File

Tags: javascript, html, file, save, blob

I have this simple html and css code

```js
function saveTextAsFile() {
    var textToWrite = document.getElementById('textArea').value;
    var textFileAsBlob = new Blob([ textToWrite ], { type: 'text/plain' });
    var fileNameToSaveAs = "untitled.txt";

    var downloadLink = document.createElement("a");
    downloadLink.download = fileNameToSaveAs;
    downloadLink.innerHTML = "Download File";
    downloadLink.href = window.URL.createObjectURL(textFileAsBlob);
    downloadLink.onclick = destroyClickedElement;
    downloadLink.style.display = "none";
    document.body.appendChild(downloadLink);

    downloadLink.click();
}

var button = document.getElementById('save');
button.addEventListener('click', saveTextAsFile);

destroyClickedElement = (event) => { document.body.removeChild(event.target); }
```

```html
<textarea id="textArea"></textarea>
<button type="button" value="save" id="save">Save</button>
```

The JavaScript code works as i want, when i click on save button it saves a file with name "untitiled.txt" for me, but for some reason firstly this code doesn't work on this stackoverflow snippet section & secondly, is there any other way to save a file with text from the textArea inside it ?

Like i don't want to do this appendChild and all

Comment: You actually don't need `document.body.append`

Comment: @Ameer No it doesn't work on FireFox or Brave i have tried